# Green spots on wood. Is this mold? (pallet bed)

Tags: wood, mold, bedroom

I've noticed greenish spots on my pallet bed. Is this mold or just some strange colouring?

There's no visible spores or "dust", but the mattress was right on top of that, so maybe there was no space for that.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks like some kind of mold/fungus.  A wipe down with bleach should kill it.  Most spores are very tiny.

Comment: ProTip™: If you ever buy poplar, then no, the green is _not_ mold, it's just that poplar can/does have green areas in the wood.

Comment: @FreeMan interesting! But it looks like the colour is relatively even then, no spots? For example: https://www.hearnehardwoods.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/02/poplar_sample_photo_04.jpg

Comment: Hence my use of the words "green areas". Not everything odd is mold, not every mold is bad for you or something to worry about.

Comment: Well, "pallet bed" so you *may* have a copper-containing wood preservative there causing staining, though that's *relatively unusual* for *most* pallets. But when you start form pallets, you really don't know what you have, wood-history-wise. Could be remains of something that dripped on it in shipping.